# Google analytics: two websites and one set of stats?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two websites:

http://unit.example.edu

and

http://m.unit.example.edu

The second website is a smartphone version (simplified, just a few pages of basic information) of the first website. The first website already has google analytics code there.

The top of the pages of the first website has code for detecting a visitor's device. If it is smartphone, directs the access to the mobile website. The first website's google analytics code is in the bottom of its pages.

Now I need to put google analytics into the second website.

I hope to be able to see the combined stats of both websites without manual addition. If possible, I also I want to see the stat of just for the second mobile website.

Should I just reuse the google analytics code (see below) in the second website? What is the right way?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." :
"http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost +
"google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-YYYYYYY-1");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
</script>
```

Regards.

Comment: What's wrong with the implementation as suggested on  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?hl=en#domainSubDomains ?

Comment: Further suggested reading: http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/ (hint: add filters)

Comment: @ravb79, thanks so much for your input. According to your first comment, I should the same account number, use BOTH asynchronous 
traditional and tracking on each website, and use pageTracker._setDomainName('unit.example.edu). Correct? Regards.

Comment: Indeed, I believe that's all. The configuration of data streams occurs on view level and/or through setting filters.

Comment: I still have this question: do I need to use BOTH asynchronous tracking and traditional tracking on EACH website? Or just use one of them (follow the customization in your link) for each website? Best.

Comment: Such a setup should allow me to see combined stats in google analytics? Sorry to ask you again. Just wanted to make sure I did everything right before launching the second website.

Comment: If you create a post instead of comment, I will select it as the answer. Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, an answer.

I'd keep only the UA (Universal Analytics) tracking script on both sites. Make sure you test it first before relying on it to gather data correctly (easily monitored via analytics' real time metrics). Then set the proper views and filters. You can make multiple views to make sure you have everything set up correctly. One view should always be unfiltered (in case something is wrong with one of your filters; GA doesn't save filtered out data).